# POST requests with Nodejs (Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client js)

Tags: node.js, post, get, postman, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'll tell you my problem, some time ago I started a project using the whatsapp api in principle it was going to be just a bot, but I decided to extend it and make a frontend that in addition to having a bot a person can give support.

I've been wanting to make a POST request to the server (fly.io) where the code is hosted, the problem is that when I make a GET request it returns the results without problem, but with POST the same thing doesn't happen.

The code is the following:

```
    async function sendTextFront(textResponse, number){ 
    
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",    
            "recipient_type": "individual",
            "to": number,
            "type": "text",
            "text": {
                "preview_url": true,
                "body": textResponse
            }
        })
        whatsappService.SendMessageWhatsApp(data);
        await makeRequest(data);
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    };
    
    async function makeRequest(data) {
        let config = {
            method: 'post',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: 'https://***.fly.dev/whatsapp/api/sendmessage',
            headers: { 
              'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            },
            data : data
          };
        try {
            const response = await axios.request(config);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

This is how I have configured to make the POST request to appear to me, then in the routes I have set up the following:

```
    .post(`/api/sendmessage`, (req, res) => {
        const dat = whatsappController.send(req, res)
        if (dat) {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                data: datos,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: "Error to send the message",
            });
            console.log(dat);
        }
    })
```

I should clarify that the index file is configured as follows:

```
    const appname = process.env.FLY_APP_NAME;
    
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
    
    const HOST = "0.0.0.0";
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.use("/whatsapp", apiRoute);
    
    app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => (console.log(`Server listen in port: ${PORT} and Host in: ${HOST}`)));
    console.log(`Back end in: https://${appname}.fly.dev/whatsapp/messages`);
```

When sending by postman a post request to the url (https://----.fly.dev/whatsapp/api/sendmessage) the message arrives without problem to whatsapp because I use a function that I have established whatsappService.SendMessageWhatsApp(data); and it sends the messages using the whatsapp api.

But this same if I enter the url that should show me the data https://----.fly.dev/whatsapp/messages shows me nothing, and I get **Cannot GET /whatsapp/api/sendmessage**

Which gives me to understand that it is waiting for a get method, which as you will see in the routes I do not have it declared like that.

I attach an image of what postman shows me (the url for this case is modified for security purposes):

[image]

And I also show you what I see in my browser

[image]

Lastly fly.io when receiving the request from postman shows me these errors

```
 gru [info] node:internal/errors:491

 gru [info] ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

 gru [info] ^

 gru [info] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

 gru [info] at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)

 gru [info] at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)

 gru [info] at Object.send (/app/src/controllers/whatsappControllers.js:81:25)

 gru [info] at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {

 gru [info] code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'

 gru [info] }

 gru [info] Node.js v18.13.0

 gru [info] INFO Main child exited normally with code: 1

 gru [info] INFO Starting clean up.

 gru [info] WARN hallpass exited, pid: 238, status: signal: 15 (SIGTERM)
```

I understand that it could be a headers error, I can not send 2 post requests at the same time to different destinations? If someone has an answer about how to receive the post request with the response through the browser and bring me the data I would appreciate it, also I do not know if with the post method I must specify some configuration to the server more than the one I set in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can't send response twice in http

therefore, when you want to send the 2nd time, check if the 1st response has been sent, if not, you can send your 2nd response

to check this

```
console.log(res.headersSent);
```

P.S: it's not two destinations because the Response object is one

Comment: Sure, but I'm sending a post request to whatsapp (whatsappService.SendMessageWhatsApp) and at the same time I want to use the function makeRequest to show the request in the browser to see it in the front end, the whatsapp request (which is not uploaded here) is sent, but the makeRequest one is not.